# Displaying drawable in textview alongside text

Tags: java, android, listview, android-drawable, spanned

I have a custom implementation of emoticons for an upcoming app. I want the user to select an emoji, which will then be inserted in an edittext and he can the add more text to his liking. When the user clicks on a button, I want to add the edittext content to an ArrayList which will be passed to an adapter for display in a textview listview item.
Initially this was my implementation.

```
private ArrayList<Spanned> chats;
private EditText content;
-------
Spanned sp = content.getText();                 
chats.add(String.valueOf(sp));
content.setText("");                    
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And then in the adapter class this is how i displayed the content.

```
private ArrayList<Spanned> comments;
-------

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatlist_item, null);         
    }

    final Spanned item = comments.get(position);
    TextView fans_image = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
    fans_image.setText(item);

    -------
}
```

The above implementation worked fine. But now I want the ArrayList to have String items instead of Spanned items. 
I am trying the following implementation.
In my Activity:

```
private ArrayList<String> chats;
------
Spanned sp = content.getText();                 
chats.add(String.valueOf(sp));
content.setText("");                    
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And in the adapter:

```
private ArrayList<String> comments;
--------
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatlist_item, null);         
    }

    final Spanned item = Html.fromHtml(comments.get(position));

    TextView fans_image = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
    fans_image.setText(item);

    return v; 
}
```

This does not work. Instead, the text is displayed correctly but the emoticon drawable is replaced with an some text almost similar to `:obj:`. How can I display the drawable alongside the text?